# How do I add delay in every some request in line

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to create a form sending request on every line but it seems the setTimeout() not working properly
then i tried like this

```
   <script> <!--   function kirimRequest() {
       var jedamili = document.getElementById('delay').value;
       var jeda = jedamili * 1000;
       var data = document.getElementById('ids').value;
       var jumlah = data.split('\n').length;
       var x = 0; if (jedamili != null && jedamili != 0) {
        var igniel = setInterval(function rain() { if (x < data) {var xx = data.split('\n')[x];
       var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
       var hasil = data.join(",");
       //console.log(data);
       $.getJSON("https://blablabla", {
       method: "post",
       uids: hasil,
       access_token: token
       },
       function(a) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
       })
       .done(function(obj,status,xhdr){
       $('#right').append("Successful <br />");
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('#right').text("");
       }, 2000);
       //$('#out').style.background("yellow");
       console.log(hasil);
       })
       .error(function(){
       console.log("Error");
       });
        }

   //--> </script>

   <div id="right"></div> <textarea placeholder=" baris 123456789
   123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789" id="ids" style="margin:
   0px;width: 100%;height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

I expect delivery of data of each line in one by one with a delay. but it was sent without delay

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"?

Comment: Its going with no delayed

Answer (score 0):

try to write one function, which you can call. Like this:

```
function delay(f, ms) {

  return function() {
    var savedThis = this;
    var savedArgs = arguments;

    setTimeout(function() {
      f.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
    }, ms);
  };
```

Comment: can you explain me what is savedThis and savedArgs please